# NSMutableDictionary confused over how to use keys with certain code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm getting data from a database and I need to add the string field value and the record id.

However, I need this to work with some existing code...

I'm replacing this (see code below) and getting data from my database.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.allCategories = dict;
[dict release];
```

This is the file it loads...

[image]

But needs to work with these key and value search functions.

```
- (void)resetSearch {
NSMutableDictionary *allCategoriesCopy = [self.allCategories mutableDeepCopy];
self.Categories = allCategoriesCopy;
[allCategoriesCopy release];
NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[keyArray addObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
[keyArray addObjectsFromArray:[[self.allCategories allKeys] 
                           sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
self.keys = keyArray;
[keyArray release];
}
```

.

```
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {
NSMutableArray *sectionsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self resetSearch];

for (NSString *key in self.keys) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [Categories valueForKey:key];
    NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *name in array) {
        if ([name rangeOfString:searchTerm 
                        options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location 
                                                        == NSNotFound)
            [toRemove addObject:name];
    }

    if ([array count] == [toRemove count])
        [sectionsToRemove addObject:key];

    [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
    [toRemove release];
}
[self.keys removeObjectsInArray:sectionsToRemove];
[sectionsToRemove release];
[table reloadData];
}
```

Keep getting an error from this code...

```
NSDictionary *arrayTmp= [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

... loop records

int cid = sqlite3_column_int(statementTMP, 0);
NSString *category = [[NSString alloc] 
   initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statementTMP, 1)];

[arrayTmp setObject:category forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cid]];
```

Error caused by line above

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d4c500' * Call stack at first throw ***

```
... end loop

self.allCategories = arrayTmp;
[arrayTmp release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says you are sending 'count' to an instance of NSString.

My guess is that the plist at 'path' (the plist file) has a string as one of the values. As you iterate through 'Categories' you expect each value to be an array (i.e. 'NSMutableArray *array = [Categories valueForKey:key];') and send that value a 'count' message.

One of the objects you expect to be an array is a string.

Comment: I've just had a look at the file, see my edit above, the image... I think that would be root ? What should I do to workaround this ?

Comment: root is the dictionary, so no that is not it, one of the things you think is an array is a string. launch the app in the debugger, get the stack trace for where its blowing up, look up the stack trace till you get to your code setObject:forKey: has nothing to do with that error message...

Comment: Hi Jules, Did you run in the debugger? Are you just learning or trying to ship something? If you are just learning I'd say take a large step back and start simpler, if you are trying to ship something I'd say you should probably take a step back...

Answer (score 0):

- `setValue` is key-value coding method. You should use `setObject:forKey:` instead.
- `arrayTmp` should be inited with `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using wrong method:

`[arrayTmp setValue:category forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cid]];`

which method used for key-value coding (you can find more about [KVO here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1)).

The method you're looking for is:

`[arrayTmp setObject:category forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cid]];`

Moreover, you should NSMutableDictionary. The NSDictionary you're using does not support mutation. (you can find more info on NSMutableDictionary [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Cheers,
Pawel

Comment: yeah your right, I just tried NSMutableDictionary, but I'm getting a new error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d4c500'
*** Call stack at first throw: